# How is the active app terminated when an iOS device runs out of battery and shuts down?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am running my own tests, but I am also interested in others' experiences across the range of iOS devices, as well as whether this behavior is documented anywhere by Apple (because I cannot find it).

In addition, I am curious as to best practices for dealing with this situation for apps that rely on uninterrupted file I/O (like a Core Data/sqlite data-driven app).  Is the best solution to check the battery through UIDevice and not attempt to write to the DB if the battery is low?

**Motivation:** I have an iPod Touch user who is reporting significant data loss after the device ran out of battery while the app was in use.  It appears the DB file was corrupted.  Based on what the user was doing, it is likely a Core Data save operation was triggered right before the device powered down.

**Update:** I am working on getting the actual database file from the user to analyze how it got corrupted (I infer that it is corrupted because the app's current behavior indicates the persistent store is loaded and some data can be read out, but new changes cannot be saved).  I *stupidly* do not have a way to do that built into the app.  I do, however, think it is possible to extract the database file from a user's non-encrypted iTunes backup of the device using [this](http://supercrazyawesome.com/) utility.

Comment: It's my understanding from reading both online and the Apple documentation that there is a finite (short) period of time available to shutdown an application after the applicationWillTerminate method is called.  Though I haven't seen actual length of time data posted (because it would be impossible to predict) it would appear that your app is taking too long.  I too will be interested in any empirical data anyone is able to post.

Comment: Are you sure applicationWillTerminate is called in the specific case of the battery running out?  Is that in the documentation?

Comment: I know it gets called in my app - not sure if I read it anywhere.

Comment: That makes sense to me, if the app was writing to the core data store and the device terminated it would indeed leave it in an invalid state.  I think the solution here would be to understand why the data loss was "significant", this likely means you are not persisting your changes into the store often enough..

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits - Actually, the app saves almost every change to the store immediately after it is triggered in the UI, so not often enough cannot be the problem.  In this case the change the user triggered was simply altering an int value representing a status.  You are right that I need to get my hands on the actual database, see my update above.

Answer (score 1):

I guessing it's just killed in the same way as when the device runs out of memory. You should do all the saving to hard drive that you need to do when it enters the background state.

Basically always assume that once the app is gone to background it will never be brought to foreground.

Comment: My app is set up this way, which is why I am concerned by what the user is reporting.  In fact, it is pretty clear that some sort of DB save occurred and was likely interrupted, otherwise how was the DB corrupted?

Comment: I'd suggest adding some sort of temporary log feature, that adds to the log when the DB is saved? Or an option where a user can email you a dump of the database (if its possible to get a dump) so you can see exactly whats corrupted.

Answer (score -1):

Several years on with ios 5.1 and we have several reports of low battery shut downs corrupting data in our core data app also.

If this happens during a save operation, you end up with the original database (db.sqlite say) and also the intermediate database (db~.sqlite). The original was destroyed (no tables data in the database but it still opens correctly in app and just returns none of the several thousand entities that were there a few minutes ago). The fix we have was to detect this and then delete the original and rename the intermediate. I don't know if this is recommended or not, but isn't that what it is for?

The only drawback was the intermediate database filesize was several times larger. Suspicious? Oh yes my friends! But it seems to have worked.